# Lisp: Why and how does '(nil nil) evaluate to true?

Tags: lisp, clisp

```
(if '(nil nil)
    'print-true
    'print-false)

(if '(nil)
    'print-true
    'print-false)
```

In the code above, why does the Lisp interpreter always evaluate these forms to true (print-true).  I thought `nil` represented false in Common Lisp.

I am using GNU CLISP.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`nil` is false. Anything else is true. `'(nil)` is a list with one element, namely `nil`. `'(nil nil)` is a list with two elements, namely `nil` and `nil`. Neither of these expressions is the same as `nil` by itself, so `if` sees it as true.

Comment: Technically, `'(nil)` is the same as `(quote (nil))`, a list of two elements, and `'(nil nil)` is `(quote (nil nil))`.

Answer (score 2):

nil is equivalent to an empty list.

```
CL-USER> (if (list ) 'print-true 'print-false) 
; prints PRINT-FALSE 
CL-USER> (if (list nil) 'print-true 'print-false) 
; prints PRINT-TRUE
```

'(nil) is equiv to (list nil) which is different from an empty list.

Comment: `'(nil)` is `(quote (nil))`, a list literal.  That is not the same as `(list nil)`, which returns a freshly consed list of one element `nil`.